# Are links in Polaris embedded app supposed to not change url path?

Tags: shopify, polaris

I'm using Next.js with Polaris (from following their [guide here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react)). Using `Link` component imported from either Polaris or Next.js is not updating the url in the embedded app.

While the url path doesn't change, the view *does* change correctly (i.e. the component for the new path does render). Same result with breadcrumbs and `url` prop for `ResourceList`.

Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up figuring this out after many variations of trying to make links work correctly.

**Answer**: no, that's not expected behavior and links should change url path for Shopify embedded apps.

For Polaris, in order to make links change the URL you will need to install [this library (@shopify/react-shopify-app-route-propagator)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/react-shopify-app-route-propagator). There is enough instructions on the page to figure out how to install it.

**Important note on library usage**: `AppProvider` had to be in the parent component for `this.context.polaris.appBridge` to work correctly. All the logic for context needed to be in a child component. This issue might've been unique to just my case, but maybe not.

Comment: Where did you see this library mentioned? I have been fighting with the app URLs for days now.

Comment: For me this library doesn't seem to help with anything. At the moment I am manually calling replace on AppBridge's history every time a route changes, but what I still can't get to work is the home page button (the breadcrumb that has the app name). It causes a full page reload. I'm suspecting it's because it points to path "", not "/".

Comment: Well, after reading their code I see they are doing exactly what I was, maybe in a bit more sophisticated way as they don't require to attach any custom listeners to links, but just handle the thing on component mount/update. This doesn't solve my problem of full page reload when I click on the app name though :(

Comment: If you don't mind sharing your code I might be able to tell you why it isn't working. It is a small library so doing it yourself is also an option like you outlined. I do not get full page reload when clicking app name either.

Comment: When you click on app name do you not have a full page reload?

Comment: No, I do not get a page refresh. Here's example boilerplate Shopify Koa app I'm building to use as reference for future projects, this may be useful to you: https://github.com/juliantrueflynn/shopify-koa-app-example (use the complete-app directory example). Note: in local dev it takes a moment for url to change and you will see component render before url changes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I don't think it's anything I can control with the code on my side. The parent window where the button lives says the frame is to be reloaded and so it is. All I can see from my embedded app's frame is the unload event. If I subscribe to AppBridge actions I see there's an APP::NAVIGATION::REDIRECT::APP action, but I can't do anything about it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was assuming you were using the embedded app, which is the only thing I've worked with Shopify's API.

Comment: I am building an embedded app.

Comment: Then you don’t use app bridge actions. Embedded app has directive ways of handling links (if I understand what you are doing). If you share code you are working with I can take a look any maybe help out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188192/discussion-between-jbasko-and-julian-flynn).

Comment: @jbasko ended up being a very easy fix for my example repo. I was using Polaris `Link` and not React Router's `Link`. Now there's no more full page refresh when clicking links--thank you for bringing up that issue.
I now see the title/breadcrumb problem too you brought up. I wrote a ticket to Polaris team to view the issue, if you want to thumbs up or follow the ticket: https://github.com/Shopify/polaris-react/issues/1028

Comment: Cool. On Monday they replied to my ticket and said it’s on their roadmap, not a bug. https://github.com/Shopify/polaris-react/issues/998

Comment: @JulianFlynn can't make it work either, If i use provider from app-bridge-react my polaris components complaint about missing i18n even if i mention them as prop, i tried different kind fo nesting of both bridge and polaris's providers nothing has worked for route propogation with react router. :/